# Return Associative Array from Oracle Function

Tags: oracle

I would like to know what data type should be in function return when a return value is an associative array in the following code:

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_DAYS 
(
  DAY_IDS IN VARCHAR2 ,
  FromDate IN Date,
  Todate IN Date
) RETURN split_tbl /*SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST*/ AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE
D_LIST split_tbl;
TYPE weekdays IS TABLE OF number INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
D_Date split_tbl:=split_tbl();
j number:=1;
m number:=1;
K NUMBER:=1;
weeks number:=1;
t_weeks number:=0;
u number;
wday char(3);
f_date date:=fromdate;
BEGIN

D_LIST := SPLIT2(DAY_IDS);

WHILE j <= D_LIST.count loop
 u:=nvl(d_list(j),0);

select count(*) into m from days where (day_id)=u;
if m=1 then
select day into wday from days where (day_id)=u;

  t_weeks:=(next_day(To_date(todate,'DD-Mon-RRRR'),wday)-next_day(To_date(f_date,'DD-Mon-RRRR'),wday))/7;
   while (next_day(To_date(todate,'DD-Mon-RRRR'),wday)-next_day(To_date(f_date,'DD-Mon-RRRR'),wday))/7 >=1 
 loop
d_date.extend(nvl(t_weeks,0));
 D_DATE(K):=to_char(weeks);
f_date:=f_date+7;
 weeks:=weeks+1;
 K:=K+1;
 end loop; 

  end if; 
    j:=j+1;
   END loop;
K:=0;
/*
while k<=d_date.count loop
d_date.extend(2000);

if(d_date(K)=null) then

d_date.delete(K);
end if;
end loop;
*/
  RETURN D_Date;
  END;
END GET_DAYS;
```

I am already using an associative array `D_List` that has been created of varchar2 but I need it in number.

Comment: What is the receiving part. php oci8 does that by default. Also you can use sys_refcursor or a user type like `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUST_OBJ AS OBJECT (/* list of variables eg. myid number, myval varchar2(255) etc. */); CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_TBL IS TABLE OF CUST_OBJ;`. Then using the oci, make the custom collection of `OBJ_TBL`, bind it, run query and fetch result.

Comment: What does the function do? What are some sample inputs to the function and your expected outputs? Have you tried returning `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` (and decaring `D_DATE` to be that type)? What does the `SPLIT2` function do?

Comment: split2 is another function that return associative array in varchar2

Comment: What does your function do? What goes in and what do you expect to come out?

Comment: I just want to return array that containing weeks 1,2,3 ...

Comment: @MT0. I have posted another question related to the above thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451735/get-of-rid-of-null-from-oracle-associative-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked several times "What does your function do?" and the only answer was:

> I just want to return array that containing weeks 1,2,3

So here is a function that returns an array containing 1,2,3

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa90d/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_days
RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
AS
  days SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
BEGIN
  days := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1, 2, 3 );
  RETURN days;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( get_days )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa90d/1/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_VALUE |
|--------------|
|            1 |
|            2 |
|            3 |
```

Comment: My own function work well as I got syntax from your answer as: select * from table( get_days('3:4','01-Sep-2015', '30-DEC-2015'))

Comment: Also want to know I'm getting null values as have to extend array. How to get rid it.

Comment: Ask a new question and give the function you've written, the input you are putting in to it and the expected output - you should get someone to help if you give all that information in the new question. Do not edit this question as it will destroy any value to people with similar issues and is unlikely to be seen by many people as it is an old (and answered) question.

Comment: Having question limit.